# Laravel 5.3 check what isset in GET

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Hello I have routing method:

```
// Show Sport
Route::get('/{id}/{name_to_url}', [
    'as'   => 'front.sport',
    'uses' => 'FrontController@sport'
]);
```

and method in Controller to this routing method:

```
public function sport($id, $name_to_url){

    // Team

    if (is($id.'/'.$name_to_url)) {
        $teamSport = Team::select()->where('sport_id', '=', $id)->orderBy('team_name', 'asc')->get();
    }


    return view('master', compact('teamSport'));

}
```

and query in view file:

```
  <?php
    $getLeague = League::select()->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
  ?>
  @foreach($getLeague as $league)
  <p class="league-star"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" aria-hidden="true"></span> <a href="{{ url('leagues/'.$league->id.'/league-'.$league->name) }}" class="league-list">Liga {{ $league->name }} <img src="{{ asset('flags/'.$league->flags) }}" width="auto" height="18" class="league-icon"></a></p>
  @endforeach
```

I don't really know how I can write a method which will check what exists in the GET. More precisely I have front page (home) url to this home page is "`www.mypage.com/`", now I want create new url (`www.mypage.com/football`, `www.mypage.com/boks` ...). And when user klick on button with link for example `www.mypage.com/boks` on front page they will be returned ONLY records with `boks_id`, not football ONLY WITH BOKS.
But when the user is on home page (`www.mypage.com/`) on front page is returned all records from database

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to check `$_GET`. You just need to do this:

In your route, you will need to put a `?` behind each parameters to indicate that [these parameters are optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#parameters-optional-parameters). If you don't do so, you will need to explicitly provide a route to `/` for the home page. In this case, we will just use optional parameters:

```
Route::get('/{id?}/{name_to_url?}', [
    'as'   => 'front.sport',
    'uses' => 'FrontController@sport'
]);
```

Then in your controller, simply make the parameters optional, and check if they are set or not:

```
public function sport($id = null, $name_to_url = null){

    //We first creating the builder, default to sort by team_name
    $teamSportBuilder = Team::orderBy('team_name', 'asc');

    //If team id is set, we add the extra condition in
    if (isset($id)) {
        $teamSport = $teamSportBuilder->where('sport_id', '=', $id);
    }

    //Query it and return data
    $teamSport = $teamSportBuilder->get();
    return view('master', compact('teamSport'));
}
```

Comment: Tahnks for answer, but is not correctly, because in file maste I have query: `$teamSport = Team::select()->orderBy('team_name', 'asc')->get();` I need write something like this:         `if (isset($id)) {
            $teamSport = $teamSportBuilder->where('sport_id', '=', $id);
        } else {
            $teamSport = Team::select()->orderBy('team_name', 'asc')->get();
        }`. When isset $id and  $name_to_url I need returned first variable $teamSport when not isset $id and  $name_to_url I need returned second variable $teamSport

Comment: Your problem is just about logic. The @Lionel Chan answer is good.

Comment: Anyway, what's `$name_to_url`? Does it serve a purpose here? You are checking it but you are not utilize it anywhere. Mind to explain?

Comment: @Lionel Chan `$name_to_url` is only name, the most important is  `$id`. I have ask the question, what is in GET. If get in null laravel from Controller returned `$teamSport = Team::select()->orderBy('team_name', 'asc')->get();` when in get isset $id Laravel from controller returned `$teamSport = $teamSportBuilder->where('sport_id', '=', $id);`

Comment: It doesn't work that way. In laravel the $_GET global parameters can be accessed via the global request object. But in this scenario you don't even need to check the $_GET because the framework has taken care for you. If $id is not passed in the first parameter would be null. Else it's set. I've already stated in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer because @Lionel Chan were good but you should never execute SQL requests in your view files.

You shouldn't use the PHP open tag in your view files.

This is not the purpose of a Framework like Symfony/Laravel